# defining a variable in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to place a method in a class that will replace null values with running average of non null values. Please refer to the code below:

```
class ElNinoData(object):
    # Your implementation here 
    add = 0
    counter = 0
    average = 0

    # methods
    def __init__(self , object):
        self.object = object

    def get_humidity(self):
        if not math.isnan(self.object['humidity']):  
            global add 
            global counter
            global average

            add += self.object['humidity']
            counter += 1
            average = add/counter
        else:
            self.object['humidity'] = average
        return self.object['humidity']
```

While executing this class in a method, I am getting the following error:

```
<ipython-input-40-c52c3ac6484b> in get_humidity(self)
     19             global average
     20 
---> 21             add += self.object['humidity']
     22             counter += 1
     23             average = add/counter

NameError: name 'add' is not defined
```

Could anyone please explain the error,I am relatively new to python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ElNinoData(object):
    add = 0
```

The add here is **not** a global variable,

```
            global add
```

therefore this does not give access to it, but instead looks for that actual global.

```
            add += self.object['humidity']
```

`+=` requires the variable to exist already (so that the old value can be added to), and you don't have a global `add`, nor a local one - you have a *class attribute*.

To access it directly, you can use `ElNinoData.add`, just as you would from code outside the class. Similarly for the other class attributes.

Looking up the class attribute via the instance - `self.add` - also succeeds. However, *modifying* the value then attaches a *separate* attribute to the instance, and leaves the class attribute unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the members to be specific to an object, change it to this

```
class ElNinoData(object):
    # Nothing here

    # methods
    def __init__(self , object):
        self.add = 0
        self.counter = 0
        self.average = 0
        self.object = object
```

and continue to refer to them with `self.`.

If you want them to be class-wide, leave them where they are, but refer to them via `ElNinoData.`.

In any case, you shouldn't use `global` here.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your values `add`, `counter` and `average` are not global.

In order to set these values on your class instance, you have to use `self` instead.
Something like this:

```
def get_humidity(self):
    if not math.isnan(self.object['humidity']):  
        self.add += self.object['humidity']
        self.counter += 1
        self.average = add/counter
    else:
        self.object['humidity'] = average
    return self.object['humidity']
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing here is that you have initialized the variables but not given them any values and then you are adding the values using +=, due to which python is throwing you this error.
Refer to the below code:-

```
class ElNinoData(object):
# Your implementation here 
    add = 0
    counter = 0
    average = 0

    # methods
    def __init__(self , object):
        self.object = object

    def get_humidity(self):
        if not math.isnan(self.object['humidity']):  
            global add 
            global counter
            global average
            add = 0
            counter = 1
            add += self.object['humidity']
            counter += 1
            average = add/counter
        else:
            self.object['humidity'] = average
        return self.object['humidity']
t = {'humidity' : 10}
a =ElNinoData(t)
a.get_humidity()
```

Comment: You should never have global variables in your program. It is a bad practice.

Comment: Hi Tanay, could you please explain why?